# Best way to a show a div if a specific area was scrolled (mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a call to action button ("Download now" spirted background div) that onMouseOver opens a tooptip (which is a simple div with live text and background-image).
On a mobile device \ tablet, when mouse over isn't an option,
would like the same tooltip fadeIn() if a specific area has been scrolled (page is long), after 2-3 seconds.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could query the current scroll position when a scrolling event occurs. Something like this:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MBXsz/4/)

```
$(function(){
    var elemOffset = $('#myButton').offset().top;

    $(window).on('scroll', function(e) {
        var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        console.log((scrollPos + windowHeight));
        $('span.pos').text('scrollpos: ' + (scrollPos + windowHeight));

        if(scrollPos + windowHeight >= elemOffset) {
            $('#myButton').css('opacity', 1);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Unfortunately I'm not sure how the scroll event behaves on mobile pages. Maybe you could also bind to `touchstart`.